# Zoom button in Time series plot with amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am wondering if it is possible to have Zoom botton as well as Date range for Time series plot in amChart as in below example:

https://v3.fusioncharts.com/time-series/

Really appreciate for any pointer. Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at the stock charts? Outside of the aggregate dropdown, it has everything else from your link. Here's one example https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-events/

Comment: Thanks this matches what I was looking for.